# how to deploy testing frame work to cloud using openshift. when we run tests in the pods and the pod fails, the test case execution will fail

Tags: kubernetes, testing, frameworks, openshift, jobs

how to deploy testing frame work to cloud using openshift. when we run tests in the pods and if the pod fails, the test case execution will fail. how can we deploy the testing frame work and run our test suites seamlessly with out interruptions?
I tried using kubernetes jobs . but it is only for batch execution and once the job is done, the pods are terminated. is there any way to deploy our testing frame work other than this.